# getting deleted users in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i am using the webside's database which was created from wordpress.

i am trying to get all users from wp_users table with sql query. But there is also previously deleted users in `wp_users` table. I searched other tables like `wp_usermeta` but i couldnt find any status or column which identifies if that user deleted or not.

Are there any table or column where wordpress website store information about deleted users?

Comment: it's probably a variant on the `user_status` column (guessing based on the [schema I've found](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description).

Comment: if you don't get an answer here be sure to check http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

The user_status column is deprecated and has been for a while. I just created and deleted a user, and it was completely removed from the database. Are you sure the database contains deleted users?

Comment: this should probably be a comment, fyi.